# Email AMP Gmail

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Is it possible to use amp-3q-player with the new functionality amp for gmail?

I mean, in the AMP documentation they have a element named "amp-3q-player" to embed videos, but I am not shure if this tag will work in a email.

Has anyone managed to apply it in an email?

Answer (score 0):

No, `amp-3q-player` is not supported in AMP for Email. The list of supported components is listed in the [AMP for Email specification](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-email-format.html?format=email).